# Naive question regarding inductively constructing hereditarily finite sets

Tags: induction, set-theory

According to my textbook, one can inductively construct hereditarily finite sets as:

$V_0= \emptyset$ - the empty set

$V_{n+1}= V_n\cup P(V_n)$ where P is the power set. (Which can be shown $V_{n+1}=P(V_n))$

This type of construction closely elaborated on here: [Inductive definition of power set for finite sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150778/inductive-definition-of-power-set-for-finite-sets)

So I think my particular problem lies in understanding induction.

If you just follow the iteration, I am wondering how you get anything other than sets involving $\emptyset$?

I.e., with $n=0$ then $V_1= \emptyset\cup P(\emptyset)$, etc.

I'm sure I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: We can also write $V_{n+1}=P(V_n)$  because each $V_n$ is a transitive set, which means that members of $V_n$ are also subsets of $V_n,$ or,equivalently, that $V_n\subset P(V_n).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
V_1 = \{ \emptyset \},
$$

$$
V_2 = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} \},
$$

$$
V_3 = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset\}, \{ \{ \emptyset\} \}, \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \} \}
$$

Notice that $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \} \in V_3$ and $\emptyset \not \in \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$.

Similarly $ \{ \{\emptyset \}, \{ \{ \emptyset \} \} \} \in V_4$, ... and you can get arbitrarily 'far away' from the empty set. On the other hand, in $\operatorname{ZFC}$ all sets are built up from the empty set via powersets and unions so, in a way, they all 'involve the empty set' in some way or another.

Comment: Thanks - I was just about to respond to your comment and you kindly elaborated what my question entails. So if I correctly interpret you answer, hereditarily finite sets look uniquely as you portray them. Regards,

Comment: It's not true that "in ZFC all sets are built up from the empty set via powersets and unions". There are models of ZFC inconsistent with that statement.

Comment: @LeeMosher In reading further in the text from whence my question came, I think the "all sets" remark should be for all sets ZF-infinity can prove to exist.

Comment: Also Rene S's answer and in particular Asaf's comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863777/in-sfzf-is-every-finite-set-also-hereditarily-finite?rq=1

Comment: @Lee can you clarify what precisely you mean?

Comment: @LeeMosher Not sure what your claim is. But it's a theorem of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ that all sets appear somewhere in the von Neumann hierarchy $(V_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord} )$ which is built - from the empty set - via taking powersets and unions. Clearly, from the outside, things may look differently but that's not accessible to our theory. (Looking at ill-founded models for example.)

Comment: I see, I may well have misunderstood something about set theory. I thought such theorems were indeed true with extra axioms that are stronger than choice, such as the axiom of constructibility, but were false under some forcing axioms.

Comment: @LeeMosher I see. As I've said, this is provable in $\operatorname{ZF}$ and thus also true in all forcing extensions. The axiom that is crucial to this fact is the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). Without that, or if you allow for [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement), you may indeed not catch every set in the von Neumann hierarchy.